# Storing MySQL Database Items In An ArrayList In Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

I am using JDBC to connect to my MySQL database and I need to retrieve all the items in my table and store them in an ArrayList. Here is the code I am using:

```
Connection con;
Statement statement;
ResultSet resultSet;
ArrayList<String> inventorySet = new ArrayList<String>();
ResultSetMetaData md;

try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, root, password);

    statement = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT inventory FROM inventory");
    md = resultSet.getMetaData();
    for(int i = 1; i <= md.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        inventorySet.add(resultSet.getString(i));
    }
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:781)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5162)  
    at Inventory.main(Inventory.java:136)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `resultSet.next();` before you try access data from a row.  According to your query you are selecting 1 column "inventory" from table "inventory".  So I am not sure why you are getting a column count because there will be only 1 column.

Also if you want to loop through all the records you should use a loop like:

```
while(resultSet.next())
{
    //code here
}
```